# Subset dataframe based on column value using a function in R

Tags: r, function, subset

I am trying to subset a dataframe with the following function.

```
SubsetDF <- function(DF, VAR, YEAR){
   DF2 <- DF[DF$VAR <= YEAR, ]
   return(DF2)
 }

test <- SubsetDF(myData, "YEAR", 2000)
```

The resulting "test" is empty. What am I missing here?
By the way, if I just do below, then the resulting dataframe is fine.

```
 myData[myData$YEAR <= 2010,]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
SubsetDF <- function(DF, VAR, YEAR){
   DF2 <- DF[DF[VAR] <= YEAR, ]
   return(DF2)
 }

test <- SubsetDF(myData, "YEAR", 2000)
```

Just replace the `DF$VAR` part with `DF[VAR]`

Answer (score 3):

An approach using non-standard evaluation

```
d <- data.frame(YEAR = 1996:2005, x = 1:10)

test <- function(df, name, year){
  df[eval(substitute(name), df) <= year, ]
}

test(d, YEAR, 2000)
```

Notice that the year variable is not passed as a character (this is what is meant by non-standard evaluation).  For more on non-standard evaluation read this http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html