# How to write a function() with arguments x,y that only returns values from column x that are == y

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:5, b = 1:5, c = 1:5, d = as.factor(1:5))
```

I want to write a function that takes as its argument one of the columns a,b or c, and one of the factors of column d, and returns only the values of column a, b, or c, that have said factor value for column d.

I tried the following code:

```
fun1 <- function(x,y) {
      u <- x[data$d == "y"]
       return(u)
   }
```

and I keep getting back `numeric(0)` as the output of the function. When I try similar code outside of the `function()` environment, it appears to work fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: note that `df` is an existing command (the F distribution), so you should probably use another variable name.

Comment: df was just for the example, it's called something differently in my real code.

Comment: Can you show your intended result for the example data?

Comment: Should you have a comma inside the dataframe brackets in your function? i.e. `u <- x[data$d == "y", ]`
Also, what is `data` in your function?

Comment: For my intended result, I just want a list of the variables of the column you designate that also have the factor you designate for column d. When I add a comma it says "incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: You need to post the actual _code_ you intend to use. At the moment it's unclear how your column specification was intended to be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a duplicate but I don't know how I would find it in the haystack of items with tags: `data.frame`, `indexing`, `columns`, `values`. Best practice is to pass the "data" as well as the search terms. (Calling  the object `df1` rather than `df`.)

```
 fun1 <- function(dfrm, col,val) {
       u <- dfrm[dfrm$d == val , col]
        return(u)
    }
fun1(df1, 'b', 3)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try this with my actual data, I get  Error in `[.data.frame`(dfrm, dfrm$d == val, col) : 
  object 'factornamehere' not found

Comment: @42- It sure is a dupe.  I only know this because I've answered it a bunch.  Here is the 42- way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935313/how-to-create-a-for-loop-in-r-for-this-peculiar-calculation.  Here is a more advanced approach using non-standard evaluation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133980/passing-a-variable-name-to-a-function-in-r/34079727#34079727

Comment: We can only know if the second one is a dupe if the OP actually posts the calling method he had in mind ... rather than posting reports of errors without the supporting code.

Comment: @42- good point on the second.  Here is a better example using non-standard evaluation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076956/subset-dataframe-based-on-column-value-using-a-function-in-r/34077429#34077429