# How to create a nested for loop in R for this (second) peculiar calculation

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I have an upgrade of this loop,(my previous post) [How to create a for loop in R for this peculiar calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935313/how-to-create-a-for-loop-in-r-for-this-peculiar-calculation)
But, this time i would like to apply the loop for different column.
Given these different dataframes `df(A)` (nrow=10,ncol=5) , `df(B)` (nrow=3,ncol=2), `df(C)`(nrow=4, ncol=2), `df(D)` (nrow=6,ncol=1)

```
 df(A)                                    df(B)        df(C)         df(D)
col1  col2  col3  col4   col5           col1 col2     col3 col4      col5                 
1      2      4     4      2              1   4         5   4          5
3      5      7     2      1              2   7         7   5          6
5      7      6     6      3              3   9         8   7          1
6      9      5.9   8      6                            8   9          4
9      11     8     4      9                                           8
4.5   5.5     7.9   6      7.3                                        10
21    6.7    13.6   8.7    2     
3.5   5       6     6     6
6     7.9     1     9     7
67     4      2     2     6
```

I'd like to:

- multiply each value of the columns in `df(A)` with those of `df(B)`, `df(C)` and `df(D)` of the correspondant column (see te name of the column of  `df`)
- and than sum three,four or six consecutive results starting from every row.

Let me give you an example:

```
A[1,1]*B[1,1] + A[2,1]*B[2,1] + A[3,1]*B[3,1]= 1*1+3*2+5*3= 22 # first expected result 
A[2,1]*B[1,1] + A[3,1]*B[2,1] + A[4,1]*B[3,1]= 3*1+5*2+6*3 = 31 # second expected result
...........
A[8,1]*B[1,1] + A[9,1]*B[2,1] + A[10,1]*B[3,1]= 3.5*1+6*2+67*3 = 216.5 # last expected result
```

and so on starting from each value of the first two column of `df(A)` (until the last possible triplet), for `df(B)`. Successively, the col3 and col4 of `df(A)`for col3 and col4 of `df(C)`summing for the 4 value,until the last 4 added value, like this:

```
`A[1,3]*C[1,1]+A[2,3]*C[2,1]+A[3,3]*C[3,1]+A[4,3]*C[4,1]= 4*5+7*7+6*8+5.9*8= 164.2 first expected result
A[2,3]*C[1,1]+A[3,3]*C[2,1]+A[4,3]*C[3,1]+A[5,3]*C[4,1]= second expected result
A[7,3]*C[1,1]+A[8,3]*C[2,1]+A[9,3]*C[3,1]+A[10,3]*C[4,1]= last expected result
```

and so on for the col3 and col4 of `df(A)` respectively for col 3 and 4 of `df(C)`.

Finally the col5 of `df(A)` for `df(D)`, until the last 6  possible value that can be added

```
A[1,5]*D[1,1]+A[2,5]*D[2,1]+A[3,5]*D[3,1]+A[4,5]*D[4,1]+A[5,5]*D[5,1]+A[6,5]*D[6,1]= 2*5+1*6+3*1+6*4+9*8+7.3*10= first result 


A[2,5]*D[1,1]+A[3,5]*D[2,1]+A[4,5]*D[3,1]+A[5,5]*D[4,1]+A[6,5]*D[5,1]+A[7,5]*D[6,1]=  second result       

A[5,5]*D[1,1]+A[6,5]*D[2,1]+A[7,5]*D[3,1]+A[8,5]*D[4,1]+A[9,5]*D[5,1]+A[10,5]*D[6,1]=  last expected result
```

The expected result is a data frame with 5 colum, and number of row which depending for which column of `df B C` and `D`  is multiply fos the respectively column of `df(A)`. For this reason the number of row of the expected `df` can be equal to the last operation of `df(A)col5` for `df(C)`, with 5 total row.

I tried with this for loop code:

```
for (i in 1:dim(A)[1]){              
  for (j in 1:dim(A)[2]){
    if(j <=2){
      results[i,j] <-colSums(A[i:(i+2),1:2]* B)
    }   

    if(j >=3 & j<=4){
      results[i,j] <- colSums(A[i:(i+3),3:4]* C)
    }

    if(j>4){
      results[i,j] <- colSums(A[i:(i+5),5]* D)
    }
  }
}
```

but R replies

```
Error in results[i, j] <- colSums(A[i:(i + 2), 1:2] * B) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 2):

Import your data (please make this easier next time):

```
A <- read.table(text = "col1  col2  col3  col4   col5                 
1      2      4     4      2            
                3      5      7     2      1            
                5      7      6     6      3             
                6      9      5.9   8      6                        
                9      11     8     4      9                               
                4.5   5.5     7.9   6      7.3                                   
                21    6.7    13.6   8.7    2     
                3.5   5       6     6     6
                6     7.9     1     9     7
                67     4      2     2     6", header = TRUE)

B <- read.table(text = "col1 col2                 
1   4       
2   7         
3   9      ", header = TRUE)

C <- read.table(text = "ccol3 col4              
5   4   
7   5     
 8   7    
8   9 ", header = TRUE) 

D <- read.table(text = "col5                 
5
6
1
4
8
10", header = TRUE)
```

Combine `B`, `C`, `D`:

```
filters <- c(B, C, D)
```

Use `filter`:

```
mapply( #loop over corresponding pairs
  stats::filter, #function for linear filter 
  A, #use first, second, ... column of A 
  lapply(filters, rev), #use first, second, ... filter, but reverse them first
  sides = 1 #filter not centered, but for past values
)
#       col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
# [1,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# [2,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# [3,]  22.0 106.0    NA    NA    NA
# [4,]  31.0 150.0 164.2 140.0    NA
# [5,]  44.0 190.0 188.2 130.0    NA
# [6,]  37.5 162.5 198.5 146.0 188.0
# [7,]  81.0 142.8 257.5 172.3 143.4
# [8,]  57.0 113.9 252.1 160.9 165.2
# [9,]  46.0 132.9 190.7 190.5 217.3
#[10,] 216.5 111.3 134.0 145.8 230.8
```

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the expected results. I would like the loop for like the previous post, but changing the number of row , maybe i have a difficult to explain the problem.

Comment: Well you don't show the expected result. As far as I understood your question this is what you want, maybe except maybe some formatting which should be easy for you.

Comment: Sorry, the expected result is correct. You are rigth!! The problem is that my TRUE df(A) is with 1356 row and 14 colum. When i try to apply your filter function with peridod 12,24,36 for respectivly df B[1:12,1:7],C[1:24,1:4],D[1:36,1:2] (and not 3-4-6,it was only for semplify) the expected result is only for the first 7 column (the number of column of the true df(B)) and NA for all remaining column. You know why? (if i explained well)

Comment: Roland...i'm very sorry, now the function work..my fault!! Thank you very much!!! all the best